# How to search string and get values?

Tags: php, string, search

How can I do the following? For example I have this text (it's a source code):

```
Welcome to asdfasdf, <h2>Welcome</h2>, <a href="index.php?my_id=1">Homepage</a>,
<br />, Hi, this is some text. 
Check <a href="index.php?my_id=12945">this link</a> or 
<a href="index.php?my_id=138>this link</a> for more information.
<br /><strong>Thanks</strong>
```

Now I would like to search this string with php for "my_id" and display all the id's. So the output would be:

```
1
12945
138
```

Hope you understand me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<?php

$str='Welcome to asdfasdf, <h2>Welcome</h2>, <a href="index.php?my_id=1">Homepage</a>,
<br />, Hi, this is some text. 
Check <a href="index.php?my_id=12945">this link</a> or 
<a href="index.php?my_id=138>this link</a> for more information.
<br /><strong>Thanks</strong>';


$res = array();
preg_match_all('~<a[^>]*?\?my_id=([0-9]+)[^>]*?>~uis', $str, $res);

print_r($res);
```

My regexp is not very strict, but it requires that ?my_id=123 appears inside `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much! But sometimes it is not inside <a>, but for example like this: onclick="Send("report_id=40983129')"

Comment: @Jordy, take my regex it works. The HTML parser I added, won't cover that case.

Comment: @Jordy, if you want to be less strict, try this:
preg_match_all('~\?my_id=([0-9]+)~uis', $str, $res); .
This will find ids anywhere in string.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a regular expression over your html string to extract the isolated numeric values with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
$ids = preg_match_all('/\b\d+\b/', $html, $m) ? $m[0] : FALSE;
```

Gives you in `$ids` the following result:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "1"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "12945"
  [2] =>
  string(3) "138"
}
```

However, the general saying is, that you should use a HTML parser to obtain these values:

```
$ids = array_reduce(
    simplexml_import_dom(@DomDocument::loadHTML($html))->xpath('//a/@href')
    , function($a, $v) {parse_str(parse_url($v, 6), $m); @($m = $m['my_id']) ? $a[] = $m : 0; return $a;}
);
```

This gives you the same result, but it will *exactly* look into the `href` attribute of `a` tags, then parsing the URL and returning only the `my_id` query value if it is set inside such a URL.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all digits up until the first non-digit character after the "my_id=" string.

```
$pattern = "@my_id=(\d+)@i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $inputString, $matches);
```

You should find the matched items in the $matches[1];

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("~my_id=(\d+)\">~", $html, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

preg_match_all will give you every match instead of just one like preg_match.
The regex statement will look for my_id= and then grap the numbers after it. and stop after it sees a "> if you are worried there might be white space anywhere make sure you put \s* in the regex statement.